# Session lost when opening IE window from application hosted in Outlook

Tags: asp.net, outlook, outlook-2007, asp.net-session

An ASP.NET application (actually with Silverlight but it doesn't matter) is hosted in Outlook as folder home page. In this application there's a link to open popup window, which opens a separate IE window, not in Outlook.

The problem is that in this case it seems that ASP.NET session is lost. A call to ASP.NET service has nothing in Session and Session._id is different. I suspect that Outlook has different cookies than IE.

How do I preserve session when opening IE popup from Outlook? Maybe pass session id via URL somehow, or configure this in web.config?

Note that I don't want cookieless sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in the past and was never able to find a way around it since the browser in outlook is running under a totally different process and it's not even a typical IE environment.  I had issues with pass through authentication as well if I recall.

When the same behavior is done in IE directly, it actually opens another window using the same session.

To recreate the process in IE that is occurring in Outlook just open an IE windown and go to your app.  Then open a new IE window by clicking the shortcut (not spawning it from the current IE session) and copying and pasting a link into the address bar.  This is essentially what Outlook is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try passing the value of the user's ASP.NET_SessionId cookie in the url from Outlook, then on the page that's opened in IE check for that value on the url and duplicate the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie in the response before loading the page (perhaps in an IHttpModule before the session has even been loaded for the request).

I'm not 100% sure this would work in case ASP.NET has some built-in session hijacking security in place that would prevent you from manually duplicating the session cookie somehow, but that's where I would start.